# Java methods wrongly get automatically overloaded in kotlin

Tags: java, operator-overloading, interop, kotlin

Given a Java library containing the following (condensed) class:

```
public class Vector2f {
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public Vector2f div(Vector2f other) {
        x /= other.x;
        y /= other.y;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector2f div(Vector2f other, Vector2f dest) {
        dest.x = x / other.x;
        dest.y = y / other.y;
        return dest;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Since kotlin automagically converts suitable method names into overloaded operators, I can write

```
val v0 = Vector2f(12f, 12f)
val v1 = Vector2f(2f, 2f)

val res = v0 / v1

println(v0)
println(v1)
println(res)

res.x = 44f
println()

println(v0)
println(v1)
println(res)
```

...with the completely unexpected result that `v0` gets mutated by the infix division operation. And, furthermore, that the reference stored in `res` points to the same object as `v0` Output:

```
Vector2f(6.0, 6.0)
Vector2f(2.0, 2.0)
Vector2f(6.0, 6.0)

Vector2f(44.0, 6.0)
Vector2f(2.0, 2.0)
Vector2f(44.0, 6.0)
```

Since the library also provides an overload to write the result into another vector, I was wondering if I can 'tell' kotlin not to use the provided `Vector2f.div(Vector2f)` method.

I have already tried to provide an extension method to `Vector2f` but that gets shadowed by the real member:

```
operator fun Vector2f.div(other: Vector2f): Vector2f = this.div(other, Vector2f())
                      ^~~ extension is shadowed by a member: public open operator fun div(other: Vector2f!): Vector2f!
```

Comment: If interested, [here](https://github.com/elect86/glm) a glm port

Comment: @elect using your port is the best solution there is, why don't you post as an answer?

Comment: Afraid to appear too much insistent/invasive, but since you suggested it, I'll try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd change the Java class to make its operator functions adhere to conventions better. If you can not modify that original class, you'll always have the `/` operator available to use from Kotlin when you're using it.

Since it's inside the original class, you won't be able to override it with an extension function, the original will always have priority over it, regardless of where the extension is declared or how it's imported.

You'll either have to live with the syntax being available, or if you really can't have that, you could create a wrapper class around `Vector2f` that doesn't have a function of that name publicly available.

Comment: That's kind of sad, as the library is really good. But using an operator overload that totally surprises you is just bad :(

Comment: `@kotlin.internal.HidesMembers` would solve the problem, but you know, if you work for JetBrains..

Answer (score 3):

I am working on glm port [here](https://github.com/elect86/glm)

For your example, relevant code is [here](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/_2/Vec2.kt#L175-L184)

```
operator fun div(b: Float) = div(Vec2(), this, b, b)
operator fun div(b: Vec2) = div(Vec2(), this, b.x, b.y)

fun div(bX: Float, bY: Float, res: Vec2 = Vec2()) = div(res, this, bX, bY)
fun div(b: Float, res: Vec2 = Vec2()) = div(res, this, b, b)
fun div(b: Vec2, res: Vec2 = Vec2()) = div(res, this, b.x, b.y)

fun div_(bX: Float, bY: Float) = div(this, this, bX, bY)
infix fun div_(b: Float) = div(this, this, b, b)
infix fun div_(b: Vec2) = div(this, this, b.x, b.y)
```

The logic behind is quite simple, referencing your sample, the shortest/simplest code:

```
val v0 = Vec2(12f)
val v1 = Vec2(2f)

val res = v0 / v1
```

*always* creates a new instance. This somehow follows the guidelines that were also written on the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html). And that are still there for the `inc()` and `dec()` section (it has been modified in the meanwhile).

Also is the less error prone form as possible (personal experience..)

For performance critical scenarios, when you don't want to allocate a new instance, the compromise is to give up on the operator overloading and use the functional form:

```
v0.div(v1, res)
```

that means, divide `v0` by `v1` and put the result in `res`.

In case you want the receiver object to mutate and accomodate directly the result:

```
v0 div_ v1
```

the idea behind this is to exploit the similarity behind the underscore `_` and the equal sign `=` and interpret `div_` as `/=`

Comment: I upvoted for the effort and I'll sure be looking into your GLM port instead of using the one I have right now. Since it's not providing the answer to the question ('can I make kotlin accept my operator overload instead of the automatic generated one') really, I can't accept it as correct I'm afraid!

Comment: Yeah, don't worry, I totally get it, thanks for the upvoting :) I hope it will be useful for people who will have similar issues as your